# Lowercase to Uppercase in C

Tags: c, arrays

(I'm posting this again with some changes.) I'm creating a program that would convert all the letters in the words (173528 from a text file) from lower case to upper case letters. Here's my program

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define NWORDS 173528
typedef char String[29];

void
Cap(char *Words[] )
{
    int i = 0;

    while (Words[i] != '\0') {
        Words[i] = Words[i] - 32;
        i++;
    }
}   
void
Initialize(char *Words[])
{
    int i;
    String word;
    char *pch;

    for (i = 0; i < NWORDS; i++) {
        scanf("%s", word); 

        pch = malloc(sizeof(char) * (strlen(word) + 1) ); 

        if (pch == NULL) {
            printf("Memory is no enough\n");
            exit(1);    
        }

        strcpy( pch, word); 
        Words[i] = pch;      
    }                                      
}

void
Print(char *Words[])
{                            
}

void
Free(char *Words[])
{       
}

int
main()
{
    char *Words[NWORDS]; 

    Initialize(Words);
    Cap(Words);     
    Print(Words);     
    Free(Words);      
    return 0;   
}
```

No compiler error but expected output wont display. Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Note: you may want to take a look at toupper and tolower functions from ctype.h

Comment: What is `Print` expected to do?

Comment: print all words in uppercase letters

Comment: Is it intentionally left blank?  Put some `...`

Comment: Of course there isn't any output, no attempt is made to output anything (other than if `malloc` returns `NULL`)

Comment: You did not follow most of the advice given in answers and comments of the previous question...

Answer (score 3):

```
while (Words[i] != '\0') {
        Words[i] = Words[i] - 32;
```

The approach above is wrong. To access individual character, you need to use

```
Words[i][j] // i-th word, j-th letter in the word.
```